# How to convert input as boolean type and use it in if and else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

```
x = bool(input ( "Write True or False\n"))

if  x is True :
  print("its true")
elif x is False :
    print ("its false")
```

when I write True or False I always get "its true". i want the program to say "its false" when i type False.

Comment: I cannot think of any type that will fall into your `else` case.

Comment: Depending how specific you want to be keeping it a string and checking against that string may be the way to go.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to say `if x == "True"`?  In python, an empty String will be False, but any String will text in it will evaluate to True.

Comment: "poolean"? Reminds me of "Prian".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just compare the strings:

```
x = input("Write True or False\n")

if x == "True":
  print("its true")
elif x == "False":
    print ("its false")
else:
    print("don't know what that is")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a problem with converting to `bool` because technically any non-empty string will evaluate to `True`

```
>>> bool('True')
True
>>> bool('False')
True
>>> bool('')
False
```

You can use `ast.literal_eval` though

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('True')
True
>>> literal_eval('False')
False
```

Otherwise you'll have to compare the actual strings themselves

```
x = input("Write True or False\n")

if x in ('True', 'true'):
  print("its true")
elif x in ('False', 'false'):
    print ("its false")
else:
    print("don't know what that is")
```